# Remove select fields from Group BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to group some data being returned from a SQL 2012 database, I need to work out how to group by on a certain amount of fields.

The following SQL works fine

```
SELECT MessageId, SearchedString, COUNT(SearchedString) AS [SearchedStringCount], MAX(percentage) AS TopPercent
from (
select MessageId, SearchedString, Percentage
from  table
where MessageId = '15'
) T
GROUP BY MessageId, SearchedString
```

But as soon as I add another fields in the select, then SQL is asking for it to be included in the group by, which isnt what i need.

How can I add another field to the above SQL, without having it be included in the Group By?

Ideally, I'm looking to include a Date value, like this:

```
select MessageId, SearchedString, COUNT(SearchedString) AS [SearchedStringCount], MAX(percentage) AS TopPercent, CAST(ScreenedDate AS DATE)        AS DateScreened
from (
select MessageId, SearchedString, Percentage, ScreenedDate
from  table
where MessageId = '15'
) T
GROUP BY MessageId, SearchedString
```

Comment: Suppose there are multiple `ScreenedDate` for the same `(MessageId, SearchedString)` grouping ... which date is the server supposed to return?

Comment: Hi Matteo, there is one date per screend message. I cast the date to remove all milliseconds, so that they dates are effectively the same.

Comment: Then you can actually add it to the group by clause with no collateral effect, while adhering to SQL Standard ... Or use an aggregate function, as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by using an aggregate function like max and min(that is if you either want a random one or the column is always the same) like this:

```
select MessageId, SearchedString, COUNT(SearchedString) AS [SearchedStringCount], MAX(percentage) AS TopPercent, max(CAST(ScreenedDate AS DATE))       AS DateScreened
from (
select MessageId, SearchedString, Percentage, ScreenedDate
from  table
where MessageId = '15'
) T
GROUP BY MessageId, SearchedString
```

When you use group by, all the columns(that are not aggregated) must be included in the group by section. So if you want another column to be included , there are several options depends on which results you want to get.

Option 1) the column is always the same, max or min should cover it.

Option 2) the column is different but it doesn't matter which one to take, max and min should cover that as well.

And option 3) You have to pick a specifiec one(like the latets or something) and then for each logic the answer will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server you're obliged to:

- **Option 1**: use aggregates in the SELECT list

or:

- **Option 2**: add non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY list

Other databases (for example MySQL) have what they call **extended GROUP BY** where they "... *extend the standard SQL use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause*...". In this case they return just "any value" for the non-aggregated column in the SELECT list not included in the GROUP BY. This makes sense only if you're sure that - in your query - ALL non-aggregated columns in the select list will return the same value.

With other databases (not SQL Server) I have coded a user defined function (any_value()) to return just the first retrieved value. It's useful, if pick option 1, because you don't have to waste CPU cycles looking for aggregates you don't need.